# About Warning Option "incompatible-pointer-types"

Tags: c, pointers, constants

My program(https://godbolt.org/z/Y93eG7K7s):

```c
int main(){
    int temp = 0;
    int* tempp = &temp;
    int** temppp = &tempp;
    int*** tempppp = &temppp;

    const int* intp0;
    intp0 = tempp;    // A

    const int** intp1;
    intp1 = temppp;   // B
}
```

Either GCC or Clang can compile, but both raise the same "incompatible-pointer-types" warning in **line B**. I have no problem with that warning, because `const int **` and `int **` are definitely two **in**compatible pointer types. However (in my opinions), `const int *` and `int *` are also two **in**compatible pointer types(**line A**).

Therefore **My Question** is: Why `const int *` and `int *` are considered as compatible pointer types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The GCC warning message is incorrectly phrased; the rule violated by `intp1 = temppp` is not that the operands of `=` must be compatible but that they must conform to certain constraints. Compatibility is one factor in those constraints, but it is not the factor at issue here, so the message is misleading. Although the question states Clang raises an “incompatible-pointer-types” warning, I do not see this; [every version of Clang available on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/a9P3GxGd9) reports a correct error message, “assigning to 'const int **' from 'int **' discards qualifiers in nested pointer types.”

An `int *` may be assigned to a `const int *` because the rules for simple assignment allow adding qualifiers to the directly pointed-to type. C 2018 6.5.16.1 says:

> One of the following shall hold:
>
> …
>
> — the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right; …

The unqualified type that `const int *` points to is `int`, and the unqualified type that `int *` points to is also `int`, and `int` is compatible with itself. Further, the type `const int *` points to, `const int`, has all the qualifiers of the type that `int *` points to, `int`.

In contrast, the unqualified type that `const int **` points to is `const int *`, and the unqualified type that `int **` points to is `int *`, and `const int *` is not compatible with `int *`. (Note that while `const int *` points to a qualified type, it is itself unqualified; an object of type `const int *` may be changed to point to a different `const int`; it is not `const`-qualified.) So `intp1 = temppp` does not satisfy this constraint, so the compiler warns about it.

The reason this is not allowed is it could result in a pointer to a qualified type pointing to an object without that qualifier. C 2018 6.5.16.1 6 gives an example, shown here modified slightly and with my comments:

```
const int **ipp;
int *p;
const int i = 1;

/*  The next line violates the constraints because `&p` is an `int **`, and
    it is assigned to a `const int **`.
    For illustration, suppose we suspend the constraint and allow it.
*/
ipp = &p;

/*  In the following, both `*ipp` and `&i` are `const int *`, so this is
    an ordinary assignment of identical types.
*/
*ipp = &i;

/*  In the following, `*p` is an `int`, to which an `int` is assigned. So
    this is an ordinary assignment of identical types. However, `p` points
    to `i`, which is `const`, so this assignment would change the value of
    a `const` object. The assignment `ipp = &p` above enabled this, so it
    is unsafe and should be disallowed.
*/
*p = 0;
```

> Therefore **My Question** is: Why `const int *` and `int *` are considered as compatible pointer types?

They are not compatible pointer types. As explained above, the reason the assignment is not allowed is because of rules about qualifiers, not about compatible types.

The notion of compatible types in C is not about whether one type may be assigned to another type but about whether two types are actually the same except for the parts we do not know about them. For example, an array of three `int` and an array of an unspecified number of `int` are compatible—all the parts we know about these two types are the same. They could be the same if the unspecified part is completed. Similarly, a function returning `void *` that takes unknown parameters is compatible with a function returning `void *` that takes certain declared parameters. This issue of compatibility is not related to the issue of qualifiers in assignments.

Comment: Appreciate for the accurate references and thorough explanations! The section 6.5.16.1-1 really clear my doubts! The information that you covered is slightly massive for me (a novice C user), so it actually takes me some hours to dive into the topic. But everything is just worth and Thanks again! With one more personal opinion, I prefer the explanation "because the rules...directly pointed-to type" than "The unqualified type...is compatible with itself", since I found the eligibility of line A might be more likely due to Implicitly Converted(https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/const)

Comment: I wonder if there would be any danger in allowing `const int *const *ipp;` and `ipp = &p;` so that `*ipp = &i;` would fail in this example. Perhaps I'm just pushing the problem forward - or it's not allowed because the rules would become "asymmetrical" (for lack of a better word).

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I have been thinking about that, and here are two potential issues. One, you might have a `const int * const *` that you cannot directly use to set the `const int *` to point to an `int *`. However, if an object of type `T` was not defined with `const`, you are allowed to cast a `const T *` pointing to it to a `T *` and dereference that to modify the object. So the `const int * const *` could be used to modify the `const *`. That does involve a cast, skirting a diagnostic, but is a cast C programmers know can be “okay” because it arises from a shortcoming in C.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Two, if you want to allow adding a nested `const` if you also add a `const` at the next level up, you have to craft some wording for this in the C standard. What is that wording? That may be hard to do. I do not question that it is possible, unless there is some other problem I have not seen yet, but it might be a mess and not worth adding to the standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "you have to craft some wording for this in the C standard. What is it?" - :-) Good question. Yes, a cast may not be raising many eyebrows in C so I see your point and also the point about how to make it clear in the standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil your last example seems spurious -- if someone casts away `const` and writes an object, it's up to them to be certain the object is not actually `const` .  Which in general requires knowledge of the object being written, and would not be affected by allowing this implicit conversion.