# Incompatible pointer type assignment for double pointer to constant double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, gcc-warning

I have the following code:

```c
typedef struct S1 S1_t;
struct S1
{
  uint8_t *ptr1;
  uint8_t **ptr2;
};

void get_ptr1(const S1_t *s1, uint8_t const **ptr1)
{
  *ptr1= s1->ptr1;
}

void get_ptr2(const S1_t *s1, uint8_t const *const **ptr2)
{
  *ptr2 = s1->ptr2;
}
```

If I leave it like that, I get the following warning from the GCC compiler for the function `get_ptr2`:

```bash
assignment to ‘const uint8_t * const*’ {aka ‘const unsigned char * const*’} from incompatible pointer type ‘uint8_t **’ {aka ‘unsigned char **’}
```

In order for me to mute the warning, I have to cast `s1->ptr2` before assigning it to `ptr2`:

```c
void get_ptr2(const S1_t *s1, uint8_t const *const **ptr2)
{
  *ptr2 = (const uint8_t *const *)s1->ptr2;
  return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why I need to do this cast operation here, when I don't need to do a `(const uint8_t *)` cast in `get_ptr1`?

My goal here is to implement getter functions for the structure `S1`'s members, and I want to make sure the function getting those members cannot modify them. Is the compiler throwing a warning at me because I am doing something dangerous here?

I have the `-wall` and `-wextra` compilation option flag enabled.

Comment: How does `uint8_t const *const **ptr2` make any sense? What you actually should be doing is probably `const uint8_t*  get_ptr1 (const S1_t* s1);` But exposing private members through pointers is often bad design in the first place, const or not.

Comment: @Lundin it's a simplified version of my code. In reality, I'd have an integer being returned here, representing an error code in case one parameter is NULL, or an other value depending on the error type. In my structure, I store a matrix, and I need to access it outside. Won't explain the reason why exactly, would take too long, and I only have 250 char left.

Comment: The reason `T **` cannot be automatically converted to `const T **` is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71100766/298225). This also prevents automatic conversion to `const T * const *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's allowed to assign a pointer to a non-`const` type to a pointer to a `const` type, that only applies to the first "level" of pointer.  If this were allowed, it would be possible to allow a `const` object to be modified.

For example:

```
const char c = 1;
const char *p1 = &c;
char *p2;
char **pp1 = &p2;
const char **pp2 = pp1;    // invalid char ** to const char ** conversion
*pp2 = p1;                 // p2 now points to c (no warning!)
*p2 = 2;                   // modifying a const object (no warning!), UB
```

In the above case is slightly different from yours since only the "outer level" is `const`.  If `pp2` were defined as `const char * const *pp2` then this wouldn't be possible, as the line `*pp2 = p1;` would contain an error.  This is really a defect in the C standard that your case isn't allowed, given that each pointer level in the destination type is `const` qualified.

Applying a cast, as you've done, is the appropriate fix for this case.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why I need to do this cast operation here, when I
> don't need to do a `(const uint8_t *)` cast in `get_ptr1`.

The C language spec's applicable rule for simple assignment where both operands have pointer types other than pointers to `void` is:

> the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type,
> and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue
> conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified
> versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left
> operand has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right
> operand

In that light, consider first the working alternative:

> ```
> void get_ptr1(const S1_t *s1, uint8_t const **ptr1)
> {
>   *ptr1= s1->ptr1;
> }
> ```

`*ptr1` has type `uint8_t const *`, and its pointed-to type is `uint8_t const`.

`s1->ptr1` has type `uint8_t *`, and its pointed to type is `uint8_t`.

Now evaluate the constraint:

- "both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types" -- **yes**.  both are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of `uint8_t`.
- "the type pointed to by the left operand has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right operand" -- **yes**, trivially, because the type pointed to by the right operand is unqualified.

Now consider the non-working example:

> ```
> void get_ptr2(const S1_t *s1, uint8_t const *const **ptr2)
> {
>   *ptr2 = s1->ptr2;
> }
> ```

`*ptr2` has type `uint8_t const * const *`, and its pointed-to type is `uint8_t const *`.

`s1->ptr2` has type `uint8_t **`, and its pointed to type is `uint8_t *`.

Now evaluate the constraint:

- "both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types" -- ***NO***.  `uint8_t const * const *` and `uint8_t **` are neither compatible types (which for pointer types means *the same* type), nor differently-qualified versions of compatible types.

For that, you need to understand that the "differently qualified" applies to the type itself, not to any other types in its derivation.  Thus, `int *` and `int * const` are differently qualified pointers to `int`.  `int *` and `const int *` are identically (un)qualified pointers to different types (`int` and `const int`).  And as for `uint8_t **` and `uint8_t * const * const`, these are differently qualified pointers to different types.

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve via the `const`-qualification, but the `ptr2` analog of your `get_ptr1()` would be

```
void get_ptr2(const S1_t *s1, uint8_t * const **ptr2)
{
  *ptr2 = s1->ptr2;
}
```