# Why does returning a pointer to non-const char from a function as pointer to const char in C results in "incompatible return types"?

Tags: c, pointers, const-correctness

In C, I try to implement a dynamic array of strings (much like the C++ `std::vector<std::string>`) with inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3536261/2690527.

Currently my code looks like

*string_array.h*:

```C
#ifndef _STRING_ARRAY_H_
#define _STRING_ARRAY_H_

struct string_array_t;

struct string_array_t* create_string_array( size_t capacity );

void free_string_array( struct string_array_t* array );

char const * const * get_string_array( struct string_array_t const * array );

#endif
```

*string_array.c*:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "string_array.h"

struct string_array_t {
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;
    char** values;
};

struct string_array_t* create_string_array( size_t capacity ) {
    // ... left out ...
}

void free_string_array( struct string_array_t* array ) {
    // ... left out ...
}

char const * const * get_string_array( struct string_array_t const * array ) {
    return array->values;
}
```

The function `get_string_array` generates a compiler error.
I want that function to provide the caller with direct access to the underlying array, but prevent that the caller can (accidentally) mess with the internal data structure.

Hence, I want to return what I thought is (read from right-to-left) a pointer to (the beginning of an array of) constant pointers to constant chars.

The error message is:

> Returning `char **const` from a function with result type `const char * const *` discards qualifier in nested pointer types

Why do I get that message? IMHO, this should be OK, because I am not discarding any `const` but adding more `const` to it.

Comment: This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71099439/about-warning-option-incompatible-pointer-types/71100766#71100766). Not quite a duplicate because that question asks about a warning message that GCC generated, and the phrasing of the message is incorrect. But the reason for the warning is the situation asked about in this question, and the answer covers it and shows how accepting this implicit conversion can result in a pointer to a non-const qualified type pointing to a const-qualified object.

Comment: I read the answer but got lost. Maybe I need to re-read it several times, but IMHO the answer is written in a rather confusing way jumping back and forth. Yes, I did understand that the problem is not about incompatible types, but the problem arises due to different qualifiers (const in my case). However, what I do not understand is why _adding_ (const) qualifiers is forbidden. The answer which you link to, says it could result in a pointer to a _qualified_ type pointing to an object _without_ that qualifier. Sure, discarding a (const) qualifier is bad. But I _add_ "const".

Comment: @user2690527, type qualifiers such as `const` are part of the types they qualify.  Where different type qualification creates an incompatibility, that is exactly a problem of incompatible types.

Comment: Additionally, this is incompatibility in a rules-of-the-language sense, not necessarily in a what-you-want-to-express-is-bad sense.

Comment: I have rolled back your edit. If you want to ask a different question, especially after having received answers, then please pose it as a new question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil allowing the conversion asked in the question cannot result in a pointer to a non-const qualified type pointing to a const-qualified object. The example in your link is different

Comment: @M.M: That conversion alone does not result in creation of a problematic pointer, but my answer explains why the constraints for assignment do not allow for adding a qualifier in this way, and, to allow the assignment OP proposes but not allow the assignment addressed in my answer, you would need, at least, to craft some new rules for the constraints. And that may raise other issues, as currently noted in comments to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: a "qualified version" of a type refers only to that type itself, not to other types in its derivation.**

---

> Why does returning a pointer to non-const char from a function as pointer to const char in C results in "incompatible return types"?

**It doesn't.**  That would be this:

```
const char *f(size_t s) {
    char *cp = malloc(s);
    return cp;
}
```

The controlling rule is:

> If a `return` statement with an expression is executed, the value of the
> expression is returned to the caller as the value of the function call
> expression. If the expression has a type different from the return
> type of the function in which it appears, the value is converted as if
> by assignment to an object having the return type of the function.

(C17 6.8.6.4/3)

`const char *` is a different type from `char *`, so the rules for conversion during an assignment apply, and in particular, this constraint applies:

> One of the following shall hold:
>
> [...]
>
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type,
>   and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue
>   conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified
>   versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has
>   all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right

(C17 6.5.16.1/1)

(The only other option for pointer assignment involves pointers to `void`, which does not apply here.)

In the case of a function return, the return value seen by the caller plays the role of the left operand, and the expression in the `return` statement plays the role of the right operand.

- The type of the left-hand operand is thus `const char *`, an unqualified pointer type.
- The type of the right operand is `char *`.
- Pointed-to types, as if subjected to lvalue conversion, are both `char`, so not only compatible but the same, and
- `const char` has all of the qualifiers of `char`.

All good.

---

**Your code presents a different case.**  Consider this analog:

```
char const * const *g(void) {
    char **cpp = NULL;
    return cpp;
}
```

The same provisions discussed above apply here, too, but they play out differently.

- The type of the "left-hand" operand is `char const * const *`, again an unqualified pointer type.
- The type of the "right-hand" operand is `char **`.
- The pointed-to type on the left, as if subjected to lvalue conversion, is `char const *`
- The pointed-to type on the right is `char *`.
- These are both *unqualified* types, and they are not compatible (which in this case means "the same"), so the constraint in paragraph 6.5.16.1/1 is not satisfied.

  Qualified versions of `char *` include `char * volatile` or `char * const` -- the overall type is qualified, and the pointed-to type is the same.

A language constraint having been violated, the spec obligates conforming compilers to emit a diagnostic, which is exactly what you observe.

---

**If you want to provide a `char const * const *` version of your type's internal `char **` member** then you can cast:

```
char const * const * get_string_array( struct string_array_t const * array ) {
    return (char const * const *) array->values;
}
```

However, dereferencing that pointer violates the strict aliasing rule, for much the same reason that you need the cast in the first place.  As such, you should probably take care about aliasing-based optimizations your compiler might otherwise perform, too. With GCC, adding `-fno-strict-aliasing` to your compile command would probably head off any ill effect, but formally, the behavior of such dereferences is undefined.

Comment: The strict aliasing rule allows adding `const`

Comment: @M.M -- yes, to the same degree that assignment does.  Although the SAR is a different provision, the relevant limitations it imposes are analogous.  Given a pointer `p` of type `char const * const *`,  the type of `*p` is `char const * const`.  The SAR permits accessing an object of type `char const *` via `*p`, but it *does not* permit accessing an object of type `char *` via `*p`.

Comment: @M.M: The aliasing rules allow accessing a `char` as a `const char`, but the “that pointer” referred to in this answer’s “dereferencing that pointer violates the strict aliasing rule” is a `const char * const *`. Dereferencing that would have the type `const char * const`, which is not a type the rules say may alias a `char *`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you will not be able to convince me that the rule intends to forbid `const T *` from aliasing `T *` , unless there is some commitee Rationale explicitly addressing that .  The rule is very far from being rigorously worded as we well know, and so intent must be taken into consideration.

Comment: @M.M, I don't know whether the committee knowingly considered that or similar examples, but the language it wrote is not ambiguous in this regard.  In particular, do not overlook C17 6.2.5.1/26: "A derived type is not qualified by the qualifiers (if any) of the type from which it is derived."  `const char *`unambiguously  *is not* a qualifed version of `char *`.

Comment: What possible ill effects could arise due to alias-based optimization if the SAR was violated in this specific case (either by -no-strict-aliasing or explicit cast)? All examples I have seen so far exploited some re-ordering of statements and modifying the underlying memory region through the non-const pointer after the assignment. However, this is not possible here as the conversion happens as part of return statement and the function goes out of scope after that. So I am wondering whether the SAR actually prevents some bad effects or if the SAR is overly restrictive in this situation.

Comment: @user2690527, the point of the Strict *Aliasing* Rule is to inform compilers' analysis of what lvalue expressions might alias each other.  This feeds into their decisions about optimization.  They can rely on the SAR to generate machine code that produces incorrect results if SAR-based non-aliasing assumptions turn out not to be valid.

Comment: For example, @user2690527, let `p` be a pointer to `int`, and `q` a pointer to `float`.  If the program executes `*p = 1; *q = 0; return *p;` then the compiler might assume, based on the SAR, that the assignment to `*q` cannot change the value of `*p`, and therefore emit code that returns 1 without reading `*p` back from memory.  If it turned out that `*p` and `*q` were in fact aliases, then it's unclear what value ought actually to have been returned, but the `int` value 1 probably does not reflect the contents of `*p` at the point the `return` is executed.

Comment: @Bollinger: Yes, I know that `int p` vs. `float q` example. However, this example exploits the fact that `q` is modified _after_ the address of `q` has been set to `p`. This is way I asked whether there is an actual example for the specific case at hand or if the SAR is simply too general and too restrictive in this case. Let's call it "collateral damage". That the SAR is good in probably 95% of all cases and allows for better optimization is unarguable. Interesting fact: The code at hand is valid in C++.

Comment: You don't seem quite to be tracking, @user2690527.  I used `int` and `float` because of how clearly different they are, but exactly the same is true if I use `const char *` and `char *` in their places. If `p` is a pointer to `const char *` (so a `const char **`) and `q` is a pointer to `char *` (so a `char **`) then the compiler is entitled to assume, for example, that assignments to `*q` do not modify `*p`.  It can generate code based on such assumptions that produces unexpected results if the assumption is invalid.

Comment: @user2690527, "*The code at hand is valid in C++*" -- yes.  The C++ version of the strict aliasing rule makes allowance for access via an lvalue of type "similar" to the dynamic type of the object, which is a defined term meaning that the types may vary in cv-qualification at any level of a pointer derivation.  C does not have this concept, so in this sense, C's SAR is stricter.  C compilers are therefore allowed to optimize more aggressively.  But you must already have known that C and C++ are different languages.  This is among the more subtle differences.

Answer (score 0):

This is a flaw in the language design ; the implicit conversion to add `const` at all levels is safe and should be legal.

It was overlooked originally, and apparently has not been fixed in C23, although [this similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28062095/) has been fixed.

Instead we are forced to use an ugly cast:

```
char const * const * get_string_array( struct string_array_t const * array ) 
{
    return (char const * const *)array->values;
}
```

Comment: What does “add `const` at all levels” mean? Does it mean “at each level, it is safe to add `const`”? Or “adding `const` at every level, omitting none, is safe”? Or something else?

Comment: @EricPostpischil The second one

Comment: And if we use that ugly cast, then we invite the caller to violate the strict-aliasing rule.  I imagine that you would characterize the SAR as being flawed, too.  I'll not debate that point here, but as a practical matter, we need to work with what we've got.  The cast is a way to approach the situation, but it does have baggage that should not be ignored.

Comment: What baggage do you mean?

Comment: @user2690527, I mean the strict-aliasing violations invited by that approach, as mentioned earlier in that comment and covered in a bit more depth in my own answer.  This is no minor matter, as it allows the compiler to optimize based on non-aliasing assumptions that might not actually be valid.

Answer (score -1):

Because `char` and `const char` are two different types.  Even though the const version can be easily used by the non-const version, pointers to the types are considered to be incompatible.  If they weren't you could easily cast away constness without even realizing it.

Comment: No, because `char*` and `const char*` are two different types. `char` and `const char` are compatible, may alias and the former may be assigned to the latter thanks to "lvalue conversion". The actual data here is of type `char` and it is not qualified - only the pointers were.